# check if twilio client is busy in a call or available

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I have 2 problems, 1st and most importantly i want to check if a client is busy in a call or available, 2nd i want to  check current queue Size and notify a user when they click pick a call from queue.

If client is not busy and there are no calls in a queue i want to allow an incoming call but if a client is still not busy while there are calls in a queue i don't want to allow an incoming call, all incoming calls should go to queue.

At the end i want to be able to update client status or if my client are online i should be able to indicate, maby in the database i store client and status, when the clients are online i allow them to handle calls.

currently i can enqueue and pick a call from queue.

Enqueue:

```
<Response>
    <Say>Please wait while we connect you to our available agent</Say>
    <Enqueue waitUrl="waiting.php">support_en</Enqueue>
</Response>
```

Queue:

```
<Response>
        <Dial>
            <Queue url="about_to_connect.php">support_en</Queue>
        </Dial>
    </Response>
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use Twilio Task Router to architect a solutuion like this. Take a look at this blog as a starting off point.

[How to Customize Phone Call Workflows with Twilio Studio and TaskRouter](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/06/customize-phone-call-workflows-twilio-studio-taskrouter.html)